# Select all data group by 1 column and functioned by another

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the following table in SQL Server 2012 :

```
ID int
priority int
type int 
other data columns
```

I want to query the table for the following result :

- grouped by 'type'
- get the id of top 1 max priority from all the grouped rows
- select all rows from the id's selected in the last step

Example :

```
ID      Prioroty      Type           Name
1         5            3               foo1
2         4            3               foo2
3         0            4               foo3
4         0            4               foo4
5         2            64              foo5
```

will give the following result :

```
ID      Prioroty      Type           Name
1         5            3               foo1
3         0            4               foo3
5         2            64              foo5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [ROW_NUMBER()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx);

```
WITH CTE AS
(   SELECT  ID, 
            Prioroty, 
            Type, 
            Name, 
            RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Type ORDER BY Prioroty DESC)
    FROM    T
)
SELECT  ID, Prioroty, Type, Name
FROM    CTE
WHERE   RowNum = 1;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7eab1/1)**

Answer (score 3):

```
;with cte as
(
    select
        ID,
        Priority,
        Type,
        Name,
        row_num = 
            row_number() over (partition by Type order by Priority desc)
    from dbo.your_table
)
select ID, Priority, Type, Name
from cte
where row_num = 1;
```

Comment: @AaronBertrand Ha!!! Thanks for the edit.  That's what I get for typing out a query in a browser instead of SSMS. :-)